# Anime with bad guy has a power to control blood and dressed in white

Tags: speed-grapher

So if I remember right, there was this bad guy that has power to control blood, was the main villain, and I think dressed in white. He's like a gangster or something like that.

I remember that one of the first episodes was that he went to retrieve his cash that was lent to some guys and they didn't want to pay him, so he told the guys that were with him to cover their eyes because he didn't want them to see his power. They then covered their eyes and he killed all the guys that were protecting the guy who was in debt with him.

Other episode I remember is that the same guy went to retrieve cash again from other guy, and he had it all but his son took like $10 or something like that and then the kid went back to return the money. But when he went home, the blood-controlling guy already killed his dad and he told the kid something like "*If you wanna kill me, buy me first*" or "*Get the money to buy me, then kill me*" or something along those lines.

Other episode was that again he went to retrieve his money from a guy in debt and the guy didn't have all the money, and he was about to kill him. But his little girl showed up and gave him some monopoly money and he said something like "*Looks like your daughter just saved you".

And the last episode I remember is that he wanted to get all the money to burn it and cause an economy crash or something like that.

Anyway, I hope that this is enough to help me identify this anime, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is most definitely [Speed Grapher by studio Gonzo](http://myanimelist.net/anime/198/Speed_Grapher). That scene with the boy taking a banknote to buy a ball is a dead giveaway.

This is the bad guy and his top henchman:

[image] [image]

And this is the good guy and his camera:

[image]

Comment: Yeah this is the anime, thank you very much!